# Jquery return original value on blur if the field left empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Ho can I achieve this? I want to get the original value if the user left the field blank.

This is what I got so far. [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dbsNy/)

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var field = $('input[type="text"]');
    field.focus(function() { //Empty the field on focus
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr("value", "");
    });

    field.blur(function() { //Check the field if it is left empty
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            //alert('This field can not be left empty');
            $(this).val(thisValue);
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're essentially describing the [`placeholder` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is supported natively in all major browsers. It is not, however, supported in older browsers. For broader support you will need to *shim* support for this attribute. Many options exists online that do this for you, but you could do it yourself if you like.

Essentially you want to allow yourself, and others, to use standard markup:

```html
<input name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
```

Using jQuery you would respond to the `focus` and `blur` (or `focusin` and `focusout`) events of any element having the `placeholder` attribute. If an element is focused, and has the placeholder value, you clear the element. If the element is blurred, and empty, you provide the placeholder value.

This is a bit verbose, but I've added comments to assist in following the logic:

```javascript
// Written and tested with jQuery 1.8.1
(function ( $ ) {

    // Play nice with jshint.com
    "use strict";

    // Abort if browser already supports placeholder
    if ( "placeholder" in document.createElement("input") ) {
        return;
    }

    // Listen at the document level to work with late-arriving elements
    $(document)
        // Whenever blur or focus arrises from an element with a placeholder attr
        .on("blur focus", "[placeholder]", function ( event ) {
            // Determine the new value of that element
            $(this).val(function ( i, sVal ) {
                // First store a reference to it's placeholder value
                var placeholder = $(this).attr("placeholder"), newVal = sVal;
                // If the user is focusing, and the placehoder is already set
                if ( event.type === "focusin" && sVal === placeholder ) {
                    // Empty the field
                    newVal = "";
                }
                // If the user is blurring, and the value is nothing but white space
                if ( event.type === "focusout" && !sVal.replace(/\s+/g, "") ) {
                    // Set the placeholder
                    newVal = placeholder;
                }
                // Return our new value
                return newVal;
            });
        })
        // Finally, when the document has loaded and is ready
        .ready(function () {
            // Find non-autofocus placeholder elements and blur them
            // This triggers the above logic, which may provide default values
            $(":input[placeholder]:not([autofocus])").blur();
        });

}(jQuery));
```

This particular shim only provides basic functionality. Others may extend support to changing the font color when the placeholder value is used, as well as leaving the placeholder value visible until you begin typing (this approach simply removes it immediately on focus).

Comment: Nice but you take the risk the value of a textbox change before your script copy the default value to the `data` cache.

Comment: @gdoron I make no assumptions outside of what the OP provided. Since the OP was accessing the value, I felt it was necessary for me to do the same.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I liked your answer very much! but the _"risk"_ should be noted, so I noted... :)

Comment: Is it necessary to add each function? As it still works without each function.

Comment: @user1193749 The call to `$.each` is what sets the initial values of the fields in memory. Without it, jQuery cannot *remember* what the default was for each field.

Comment: Note that `:text` selector is bad for performance as noted in the docs: _"Because :text is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="text"] instead."_

Comment: @gdoron Thanks for the note. Just goes to show, shorter is not always better ;)

Comment: There is a difference between `.focusout` and `.blur`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non jQuery answer as well:

```
<input type="text" name="zip_code" id="zip_code_value" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name'}">
```

You can just update your input tags to be like that and then you don't need jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var field = $('input[type="text"]');
    field.focus(function() {
        var placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');
        if (this.value == placeholder) 
            this.value = "";

    });

    field.blur(function() {
        if (this.value === "") {
            this.value = $(this).data('placeholder');
        }
    });
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbsNy/6/)

Regarding to `$(this).val()`:

**Know Your DOM Properties and Functions**

> While one of the goals of jQuery is to abstract away the DOM, knowing
>   DOM properties can be extremely useful. One of the most commonly made
>   mistakes by those who learn jQuery without learning about the DOM is
>   to Utilize the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an
>   element:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src');  // Bad! 
});
```

> In the above code, this refers to the element from which the click event handler was fired. The code
>   above is both slow and verbose; the code below functions identically
>   and is much shorter, faster and readable.

The [jQuery tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

Answer (score 0):

you should make thisValue a global variable. this way it would be accessible everywhere. something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var field = $('input[type="text"]');
    var thisValue
    field.focus(function() {//Empty the field on focus
        thisValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr("value","");
    });

    field.blur(function() {//Check the field if it is left empty
        if($(this).val()=="") {
        //alert('This field can not be left empty');
        $(this).val(thisValue);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been using recently:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Search" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="you@domain.com" />
...
```

JavaScript:

```
// Default Input Field Text
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#s, #email, #phone, #name").live("focus", function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == $(this).attr("rel") ) $(this).val('');
    }).live("blur", function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == '' ) $(this).val( $(this).attr("rel") );
    }).each( function(){
        $(this).attr("rel", $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

define the `thisValue` in the global scope by removing the `var`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var field = $('input[type="text"]');
    field.focus(function() {//Empty the field on focus
         thisValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr("value","");
    });

    field.blur(function() {//Check the field if it is left empty
        if($(this).val()=="") {
        //alert('This field can not be left empty');
        $(this).val(thisValue);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbsNy/3/

Comment: Didn't downvote you, But I'm not sure this is what the OP **really** wants. You just give an alert instead of give the default value again.